poetry package a subfolder as a package
I have a package structure like (I am leaving out __init__.py files in every directory and a py.typed)
folder
 |-pyproject.toml
 |-package_folder
    |-other_file.py
    |-api_folder
       |-client.py

My pyproject.toml includes:
[tool.poetry]
packages = [
    { include = "package_folder/api_folder"}
]

but this produces a whl structure that requires my consumers always type import package_folder.api_folder.client.
What I'd like is to produce a whl structure that only requires my consumer type import package_folder.client.
However, when I put the following my pyproject.toml file I get an error:
packages = [
    { include = "api_folder", from = "package_folder", to = "package_folder" }
]

results in
The Poetry configuration is invalid:
 - data.packages[0] must not contain {'to'} properties

which doesn't make sense to me.
Does anyone know the magic incantation?

You need some __init__.py files in there and hoist names up into the higher namespace.

I cut out the init.py files in the diagram because they're assumed.  What do you mean about hoist names up?

@simpleCoder You want to re-export client in the module package_folder. To do that, add the line from package_folder.api_folder import client to package_folder/__init__.py (assuming that package_folder is your top-level package).

If you look down below you'll see my solution.  @Brian61354270 you made some really good points that I needed to work through.  Thank you!

__init__.py files are not assumed.  They're the difference between a python package and a plain old directory or a namespace package, and their presence or absence is of high importance in any question related to Python packaging.

I figured it out!

Make sure you're on a newer version of Poetry, I was getting the error on 1.7.0
use the following:

packages = [
   { include = "*", from = "package_folder/api_folder", to = "package_folder" }
]

The above will take all of the files in the api_folder and produce a whl with them under package_folder.
Though now I realize that the imports will be broken so I'm changing the structure (I'm ignoring __init__.py files in this).
folder
 |-pyproject.toml
 |-package_folder
    |-other_file.py
    |-api_folder
       |-file_needed_for_client.py
    |-client_folder
       |-client.py
       |-py.typed

with
packages = [
  {from = "package_folder/client_folder", include = "*", to = "package_folder"},
  {include = "package_folder/api_folder"}
]

That's putting the client.py and py.typed at the top level of the resulting whl while keeping the api_folder's files in the api_folder so imports work
